# Fatal error when starting "make" command in redis

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, g++

I am trying to install Redis, I am trying to run the 'make' command
When I run the 'make' command I keep receiving this error:

> cc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1’: execvp: No such file or
> directory compilation terminated.

I tried the command:

> which gcc

I received the gcc location:

> /usr/local/bin/gcc

I checked also that I am using the same version of gcc and g++

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you